# Save the response from OkHttp -- Android --

Tags: android, okhttp

I wanna to save the result from OnResponse method to use it for updating the UI 
i tried to save the result into String var then call it into main thread but it doesn't work .

here's my code with some comments ,
any help ?

```
package com.example.blacknight.testokhttp;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import static android.R.string.ok;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final String URL_MOVIE = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=" + API_KEY;
    String res_120 ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL_MOVIE)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            Log.v("BK-201 URL: " , response.body().string());

            // wanna save the result to update UI
            res_120 = response.body().string();

        }

    });


    // just for test : if the result has been saved or not
    Log.i("BK-111 : " , res_120);


}
```

}

Comment: Keep in mind that tha call that are you doing with the client is asynchronous and that the callback that implements your onResponse function will be called only when this asynchronous call finishes. Because of that, the log in your UI thread will be executed before the callback and the res_120 variable will be empty. To execute the OkHttp synchronously, you should call execute(), not enqueue(), but that will block your UI thread and you shouldn't do that. You could move all the code into an Asynctask, for example.

Comment: yup , i was trying to do that to escape from using Asynctask and Loaders , so the only way to accomplish this task is by using AsyncTask or something like that ?

Comment: and generally  what is the best way to update UI using the response from OkHttp  ?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you want to do after the Call. If you want to use the call response to update the UI, you could do that in the onResponse method, you will be running on the UI thread.

Comment: I think if you want to check `the result has been saved or not` you should check after `res_120 = response.body().string();` because for current your log `BK-111` is wrong place. So for update the UI you should add the code after `res_120 = response.body().string();`

Comment: i'll try to do that , thaks :)

Comment: @Sodiq yup , the problem here is like what jofer said  "call that are you doing with the client is asynchronous and that the callback that implements your onResponse function will be called only when this asynchronous call finishes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to update a TextView element in you UI with the response in a String format. You could do something like this. I keeped your test log to help you follow the code, just in case.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(URL_MOVIE)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

            Log.v("BK-201 URL: " , response.body().string());

            // wanna save the result to update UI
            res_120 = response.body().string();
            updateUI(response.body().string());
        }
    });    
}

void updateUI(String string) {
   textView.setText(string);
   Log.i("BK-111 : " , res_120);
}
```

Comment: this code gives my NullPointerException but i catch the idea

Comment: As you say, this code is only useful to catch the idea. If you want help in a more detailed problem, just ask and we'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code for anyone have the same problem or new on using OkHttp , Unfortunately i'm using AsyncTask

Thaks to Jofre Mateu

```
package com.example.blacknight.testokhttp;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public final String URL_MOVIE = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=" + API_KEY ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MovieTask().execute();
    }


    public class MovieTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void , String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();



                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(URL_MOVIE)
                        .build();


                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                String res_120 = response.body().string();

                return res_120;

            } catch (Exception e ){

                return null;
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView_test);
            textView.setText(s);
        }
    }

}
```